# How to access AWS resources without using IAM Role or IAM User Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Let assume we have Ec2 instance and there are two applications. only one application **should** be able to access S3 bucket and other application 
**shouldn't** be able to access the S3 bucket.

1)  I don't want to use an IAM user Access key ID and Secret access key for this issue, because it's difficult manage. That is not recommended. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)

2) But I can't use IAM role . Because it's associate with the Ec2 instance and It will allow access to every applications inside that Ec2.

Comment: You can use conditions in IAM policy. If your instance id is not going to change, you can use ARN condition operators. Documentation can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_ARN

Comment: How about the idea of making your S3 bucket public, but put a policy of only the x.x.x.x public IP address can have access? Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a bucket policy to restrict access on same of HTTP header request. allows s3:GetObject permission with a condition, using the aws:referer key, that the get request must originate from specific webpages. The following policy specifies the StringLike condition with the aws:Referer condition key.

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.example.com and example.com.",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:GetObject",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
"Condition": {
"StringLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
}
},
{
"Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
"Condition": {
"StringNotLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
}
}
]
}
```

[AWS Reference Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)